# Dilema: The best way to make table column not sorted

Tags: android, sorting, android-tablelayout

I am creating android app using Kotlin. I have fully functional multi column sorting. When I click on table header column it adds it index to sorting column list. It sorts both ways (ascending and descending). On click it changes direction. Everything works fine. But I would like to know what would be the best solution to remove sorting from one column.

I have few ideas but they don't sound good:

- On third column click remove sorting on that column.
- Add button which is visible when column is sorted. Button on click removes column from sorted list.

I would like some help because I don't know how to implement this feature in a good way.

**Edit1:**

Forgot to mention that sorting happens in back-end. In android I just set parameters which columns I need to sort and then send GET request to the server. As response I get sorted data.

Comment: Hi, you should provide snippets of your attempts so people can see what you have tried

Comment: I can not provide any snippets because I have not implemented that feature. Tried to explain that using words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would mimic the way Google Spreadsheets does:

[image]

It shows a dialog and you can add sort columns and delete them.

You can see it by selecting some columns and going to `Data / Sort the range`.

Another possibility would be to have a 3 states switch in each column (sort ascending, sort descending, not sort). Here you can see it working in a website (look at the Multiple column sorting example): http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/sorting but, in my opinion, it is more confusing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to mention that sorting happens on back end server. So i just send new GET request with parameter which columns to sort. Then i get response with sorted data. But thanks for your answer anyway